# application execution terminated

Tags: java, android

My application generates this

`<terminated, exit value: 1>C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe (Dec 24, 2012 5:01:04 PM)`

What is this error? I don't understand how to resolve it so that i can execute, run and debug my application. Kindly guide

LogCat is:

```
    12-24 17:33:06.012: I/[POST_RESELECT](7761): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@4011bca8,-1,0,-1,0)
12-24 17:33:06.022: I/[POST_RESELECT](7761): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@400e4430,-1,0,-1,0)
12-24 17:33:06.032: I/[POST_RESELECT](7761): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@4011bca8,-1,0,-1,0)
12-24 17:33:06.032: I/[POST_RESELECT](7761): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@400e4430,-1,0,-1,0)
12-24 17:33:06.032: I/[POST_RESELECT](7761): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@4011bca8,-1,0,-1,0)
12-24 17:33:06.032: I/[POST_RESELECT](7761): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@400e4430,-1,0,-1,0)
12-24 17:33:06.042: I/[POST_RESELECT](7761): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@4011bca8,-1,0,-1,0)
12-24 17:33:06.042: I/[POST_RESELECT](7761): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$START@400e4430,-1,0,-1,0)
12-24 17:33:06.042: I/[POST_RESELECT](7761): [spanChange] (o, oldStart, newStart, oldEnd, newEnd)=(android.text.Selection$END@4011bca8,-1,0,-1,0)
12-24 17:33:07.212: W/KeyCharacterMap(7761): Can't open keycharmap file
12-24 17:33:07.212: W/KeyCharacterMap(7761): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/cy8c-touchscreen.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65537.devname='cy8c-touchscreen'
12-24 17:33:07.212: I/KeyCharacterMap(7761): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
12-24 17:33:08.242: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(7761): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
12-24 17:33:08.242: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(7761): InputConnection = android.widget.AbsListView$3@40531ac8, active client = false
```

Comment: post your relevant code and log also when application get crashed

Comment: @Mona, Log means logcat and not this log. try opening your DDMS and post the output

Comment: @thepoosh: Now it accurately run on my phone. i don't know how it create and interrupt and how it resolved. i just restart my PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not an Error Javaw.exe is java VM which terminated by your code

Comment: You are right. I restart my PC and again debug it then it run accurately. why this error generated???

Comment: we can help you when you post your code and logcat output sorry but i can't understand your problem.when your logcat doesn't update close your ecilpse then run it again